# facebook graph api how can we get the answered status of a message

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, message

The question is about to know if the specific message has been answered or not.

I'm able to get the messages of the inbox of a Facebook page with this

```
$facebook_graph_get_messages = https://graph.facebook.com/--page--id--/conversations?fields=id,messages{message,to,from,created_time}&access_token=....

$raw_graph = file_get_contents($facebook_graph_get_messages);
        $raw_graph_parsed = mb_convert_encoding($raw_graph, "UTF-8",mb_detect_encoding($raw_graph));

        $fb_page_conversations = json_decode($raw_graph_parsed, true);

        foreach ( $fb_page_convers['data'] as $fb_page_conver_key => $fb_page_conver_arra ) {
            foreach ( $fb_page_conver_arra['messages']['data'] as $fbpcmd ) {
                $fpms_txt = html_entity_decode($fbpcmd['message']);
                echo $fpms_txt;
```

I get fields message, to, from, created_time.... but I didn't found in the documentation how to know if the message is answered or not ...

Thanks

*** EDIT ***
Sample

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "t_...",
         "messages": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "message": "test",
                  "to": {
                     "data": [
                        {
                           "name": "...",
                           "email": "...\u0040facebook.com",
                           "id": "..."
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  "from": {
                     "name": "...",
                     "email": "...\u0040facebook.com",
                     "id": "..."
                  },
                  "created_time": "2020-04-05T03:27:49+0000",
                  "id": "m_dW...."
               }
            ],
            "paging": {
               "cursors": {
                  "before": "QVFI....",
                  "after": "QVFI..."
               }
            }
         }
      },
```

Comment: You’re getting the messages grouped by the thread id, so – every message inside a thread expect the very last one, should be considered “answered”, no?

Comment: @CBroe I edited the question and added a sample

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to consider an individual message _within a thread_ as answered, on its own. If you write three messages in a thread, and then get one response - then you have to consider yourself “having been answered” on all of them.